# SELECT subquery for dates in BETWEEN WHERE clause

Tags: sql

I want to use dates from a different table in the `BETWEEN` inside the `WHERE` clause.

How can I inject the dates? The query below works, but is **much slower** than using plain dates.

I've tried rewriting the query in numerous ways, as well as use CTEs, to no avail.

Is there a way to make this work faster?

```
select *
        from (
            select 
                ti.*,
                si.anvat as vat,
                cast(si.acName as nvarchar(255)) productNameOriginal,
                cast(su.acName as nvarchar(255)) unit,
                cast(ss.acName2 as nvarchar(255)) supplier,
                historyStart,
                historyEnd
            from tenderItem ti
                left join the_setitem si on si.acIdent = ti.sku
                left join tHE_SetUM su on su.acUM = si.acUM
                left join tHE_SetSubj ss on ss.acSubject = si.acSupplier       
                left join tender t on t.id = ti.tenderId
            where tenderId = 1
        ) t1

            left join (
                select
                    acident sku,
                    sum(anQty) historyQuantity,
                    round(max(anRTPrice), 2) historyPrice
                from the_moveitem mi
                    left join the_move m on m.ackey = mi.ackey
                where 
                    m.acDocType in (
                        '3000'
                        '3050'
                    )
                    and m.acreceiver = '11111'
                    
                    and m.addate 
                        between (select historyStart from tender where id = 1)     -- <------ THIS PART
                        and (select historyEnd from tender where id = 1)     -- <------ THIS PART
                    
                group by acident
            ) history on history.sku = t1.sku
```

Comment: have you tried adding `limit 1` to the queries, for example `select historyStart from tender where id = 1 limit 1` ?

Comment: This does nothing because there is already just one date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to solve it by using variables.

```sql
DECLARE @historyStart DATE;
SET @historyStart = (select historyStart from tender where id = @tenderId);
            
DECLARE @historyEnd DATE;
SET @historyEnd = (select historyEnd from tender where id = @tenderId);

--

and m.addate between @historyStart and @historyEnd
```